# OpenGL fragment shader for GL_LINES only renders lines when shader compilation fails

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fragment-shader

I've looked for an answer to my problem for two days. Maybe I'm just terrible at searching but there doesn't seem to be an answer already out there.

I am trying to draw lines on the screen using OpenGL's glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, ..., ...). This is the current code for my fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 vertexColor;

out vec4 color;

void main( )
{
    //color = vec3(0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    color = vec4(0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
    //color = vertexColor;
}
```

Originally the color=vertexColor line was supposed to work, but nothing appeared on the screen. I thought maybe something was wrong with the data being sent from the vertex shader so I tried setting the output manually in the fragment shader. I accidentally made it a vec3 instead of a vec4 and I got an error in my console window telling me compilation of the shader had failed. But the lines appeared! They showed up in the right spot as white/gray lines of static. When I corrected the mistake and set the output to a vec4, like shown, the lines were invisible again and I had no compilation error.

What am I doing wrong that makes my lines invisible?

Edit:
Here is my first go at a "minimal, complete, and verifiable example". If you link a project with these files to GLEW, GLFW and GLM, this should run on your system. If I'm not supposed to upload a whole program, I apologize. This seems a bit big, but I don't know how else it could be "complete".

Instead of making two white static lines, this one is making only one solid black line when the fragment shader fails to compile. It still renders nothing when compilation is successful.

Main.cpp

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include "ShaderMaker.h"
#include "TargetBox.h"


const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

//Camera 
glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
GLfloat yaw = -90.0f;
GLfloat pitch = 0.0f;

// Delta time
GLfloat deltaTime = 0.0f;
GLfloat lastFrame = 0.0f;

int main() {

    cameraFront.x = cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    cameraFront.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
    cameraFront.z = sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    cameraFront = glm::normalize(cameraFront);

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Debugger", nullptr, nullptr);

    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenHeight);

    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    if (GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);



    TargetBox tb;

    GLuint modelLoc = tb.getUniform("model");
    GLuint viewLoc = tb.getUniform("view");
    GLuint projectionLoc = tb.getUniform("projection");



    glm::mat4 projection;
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)screenWidth / screenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);


    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.5f, 0.7f, 0.9f, 1.0f); // Unnecessary, but adds some color to an otherwise blank window
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glm::mat4 view;
        view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + cameraFront, cameraUp);

        tb.useShader();

        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        glBindVertexArray(tb.getVAO());
        glm::vec3 posMod = tb.getPos();
        glm::mat4 model;
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(posMod.x, posMod.y, posMod.z));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 4);



        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

ShaderMaker.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef SHADERMAKER_H
#define SHADERMAKER_H

#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>

#include<GL/glew.h>

class ShaderMaker {
public:
    // The program ID
    GLuint Program;
    // Constructor reads and builds the shader
    ShaderMaker(const GLchar* vertexPath, const GLchar* fragmentPath) {
        // 1. Retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
        std::string vertexCode;
        std::string fragmentCode;
        std::ifstream vShaderFile;
        std::ifstream fShaderFile;
        // ensures ifstream objects can throw exceptions:
        vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
        fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
        try {
            // Open files
            vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
            fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
            std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;
            // Read file's buffer contents into streams
            vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
            fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
            // close file handlers
            vShaderFile.close();
            fShaderFile.close();
            // Convert stream into GLchar array
            vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
            fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
        }
        catch (std::ifstream::failure e) {
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESSFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
        }
        const GLchar* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const GLchar* fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();

        // 2. Compile shaders
        GLuint fragment;
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[512];

        // Vertex shader
        GLuint vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        // Print compile errors if any
        glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }

        // Similar for fragment shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        // Print compile errors if any
        glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }

        // Shader program
        this->Program = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(this->Program, vertex);
        glAttachShader(this->Program, fragment);
        glLinkProgram(this->Program);
        // Print linking errors if any
        glGetShaderiv(this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success) {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(this->Program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }

        // Delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessary
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
    }
    // Use the program
    void Use() { glUseProgram(this->Program); }
    // Get a uniform
    GLint getUniform(const GLchar * name) {
        return glGetUniformLocation(this->Program, name);
    }
};

#endif
```

TargetBox.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef TARGETBOX_H
#define TARGETBOX_H

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include<glm/glm.hpp>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "ShaderMaker.h"


class TargetBox
{
public:
    TargetBox();
    ~TargetBox();

    void useShader();

    GLuint getVAO();

    glm::vec3 getPos();
    void setPos(glm::vec3 p);

    GLuint getUniform(GLchar * u);
private:
    glm::vec3 pos;

    GLuint VAO, VBO;
    const GLchar *vertexShaderPath = ".\\VShaderLine.txt";
    const GLchar *fragmentShaderPath = ".\\FShaderLine.txt";

    ShaderMaker shader = ShaderMaker(vertexShaderPath, fragmentShaderPath);
};

#endif
```

TargetBox.cpp

```
#include "TargetBox.h"



TargetBox::TargetBox()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -2, 0, -5,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        2, 0, 5,    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        2, 0, 5,    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        2, 10, 5,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    size_t data_len = sizeof(vertices);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data_len, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    //Color attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}


TargetBox::~TargetBox()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
}


void TargetBox::useShader() { shader.Use(); }

GLuint TargetBox::getVAO() { return VAO; }

glm::vec3 TargetBox::getPos() { return pos; }
void TargetBox::setPos(glm::vec3 p) { pos = p; }

GLuint TargetBox::getUniform(GLchar * u) { return shader.getUniform(u); }
```

VShaderLine.txt

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;

out vec4 vertexColor;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main( )
{
    // The order of multiplication is important?
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    vertexColor = vec4(color.xyz, 1.0f);
}
```

FShaderLine.txt

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 vertexColor;

out vec4 color;

void main( )
{
    color = vec3(0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    //color = vec4(0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
    //color = vertexColor;
}
```

Comment: There's not nearly enough information being provided to diagnose this issue. If the lines are only showing up when the shader fails to compile, that usually implies that the vertex shader, when successfully compiled, is transforming the lines outside the windowspace. Edit in a [mcve] that includes your vertex shader and the host code.

Comment: I've never had to make a "minimal, complete, and verifiable example" before. I'll try to extract one out of my program.